# convert from html to pdf and to image java

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, flying-saucer, pdfrenderer

Well, I DID READ ALMOST ALL THE QUESTIONS HERE ABOUT THIS TOPIC!

I need **an API - not at tool** to convert in a very high quality from PDF to image.

So I didn't find any direct tool, and I used: HTML to PDF and PDF to image.

I tried:

- PDFRenderer
- FDFBOX
- PDFONE
- HTML2IMAGE
- FLYING-SAUCE
- ITEXT
- JPEDAL
- PDFCrown

Only the commerical ones (PDFCrown and PDFBox) came out with good results.

I thought that Java is for open source projects!

Am I missing any library that prints out in a high quality images from HTML (could be also from PDF, I can pay for half the way..)

Comment: what filetype do you want the images to be saved as?

Comment: does it have to be jpg? why not png?

Comment: It can also be png. I don't mind about it - It just needs to be in a high quality

Comment: ok so how are you going to tell java i want to convert html to a image or pdf to a image

Comment: I will use one library to convert to PDF and the other one to convert to IMAGE

Comment: ... lemme repfrase the question how will java know your converting a PDF not HTML?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4952/discussion-between-odelya-and-adam2510)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/ try this out

Comment: No - it's not in a high quality for text. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the wonderful tool:

[WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

It's very easy - just a command line.

Installation:

1. Download from [here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list) the version. To windows I used: `wkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-installer.exe` file.
2. Run the installer
3. Save your HTML to a file on your disk.
4. In java, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wkhtmltopdf file.jpg myhomepage.jpg)`

That's it! so easy to use:)